# How can I configure the auth parameter when using lerna publish?

Tags: npm, lerna

I have an `.npmrc` set up to publish to a private registry, but I do not want to check in auth credentials. How do I provide the `_auth` config when running `lerna publish`?

Unfortunately `lerna publish` does not accept the `_auth` flag: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/publish#options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out you can [set npm config parameters using environment variables](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables), so this does the trick:

```sh
npm_config__auth=AUTH npx lerna publish # yes, double underscore
```

Answer (score 1):

This recent PR was made to lerna which exposes the `_auth` config through the `--legacy-auth` flag.

https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/2347/files

Usage is as follows: `lerna publish --legacy-auth aGk6bW9t`

This should be available in the next lerna release >3.19.0. It has not yet been released at time of writing.